# AWS WordPress unwanted requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I'm hosting a WordPress website on AWS EC2. Over the past few weeks I have been receiving a fixed number of daily requests, incurring EC2 and ELB costs. Since the daily cost is more or less constant I assume that the calls are automated. Is there a way to block this?

[image]

Comment: Do you use route53? Could be R53 health checkers?

Comment: @Marcin I do use R53. But I doubt that the traffic comes from health checkers since my ELB is getting 5,000 - 30,000 requests per day. Is there a way to check the source?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use AWS WAF and Sheild to block unwanted traffic. There are several rules to apply in blocking and allowing traffic.

Comment: Thanks Riyaz, do you also know of any options that don't incur costs?